# How can I change the color of "ElevatedButton" depend on something else changes in the program?

Tags: flutter, button, material-design, background-color

I have a provider value like below:

```
var book = Provider.of<Books>(context, listen: false);
```

And an upload button like the following:

```
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: book['imageUrl'] == ""
                      ? Theme.of(context).highlightColor
                      : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      book['imageUrl'] =
                          uploadURL!;
                    });
                  }
                },
```

What I want to do is changing the background color of the button when the image uploaded and `book['imageUrl']` will be set inside the `setState()` function. But the above solution doesn't work!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Call `notifyListeners()` to change the state of `book`

Answer (score 0):

You can have `Consumer` like:

```
Consumer<Books>(
  builder: (context, book, _) => ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: book.imageUrl == "" ? Theme.of(context).highlightColor : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    ),
    onPressed: () async {
      setState(() {
        book.imageUrl = uploadURL!;
      });
    },
  ),
);
```